# Laravel 5.1 Middleware to check the creation date from a user to change password

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

I'm developing a webapp with Laravel 5.1 and I'm building the authentication system and I have to check if the user has not changed his password in six months or more and I would use a middleware to check this but I didn't find how I can do it properly. I created a global middleware but it is not working because I can't get the authenticated user.

It is possible that I have to use an AfterMiddleware to check the password?

Answer (score 0):

First explain/state when you want the user to force to change the password?
While authenticating or after success authentication?
then i can give you a solution

Comment: While authenticating because I want to get the user and redirect to the reset password view but I need to know that it is a valid user.

Answer (score 0):

then You need to overwrite the method postLogin in AuthController

public function postLogin(Request $request){

```
  $credentials  = ['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password];

  if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {

      if((strtotime(Auth::user()->created_at) < strtotime('6 month ago'))){
        return redirect('your-reset-path);//redirect to password reset page
      }else{
        return redirect()->intended('/');
      }

  }

  return redirect($this->loginPath())
      ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
      ->withErrors([
          'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
      ]);
  }
```

this will do the job if you want to check on created_at but you rather use another field with time-stamp(last_password_updated) that will only updated when password is changed and when it is first created,it will be more efficient.

Comment: Well, this is what I was doing in the first place but then I thought that if the user enters in another url the application has to check if the password is changed not only in the postLogin function because the user could have another url in the browser history and checked the remember me button.